# Find $\int \frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+4e^x+4} \mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+4e^x+4} \mathrm{d}x$.

**Attempt:**

We have that $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+4e^x+4} \mathrm{d}x = \int \dfrac{e^{2x}}{(e^{x}+2)^2} \mathrm{d}x$. Then making the substitution $u = e^{x}+2$ we have $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{e^{2x}}{(e^{x}+2)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{2u^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2(e^{2x}+2)}+C.$$

My problem is that I went to an integral calculator and it said the answer is $\dfrac{1}{2e^x+4}((e^x+2)\ln|e^{2x}+4e^{x}+4|+4)+C$. Why are we getting two different answers?

Edit: My attempt is wrong. How do we do this integral?

Comment: If you make $u=e^x+2$, then you have $du=e^xdx$, but you seem to have put that $du=e^{2x}dx$

Answer (score 3):

Using your substitution (there are other options too as in Ekaveera's answer) we have
$$du=e^x\,dx$$
so the numerator becomes
$$e^{2x}\,dx=e^xe^x\,dx=(u-2)\,du$$
and the transformed integral is
$$\int\frac{u-2}{u^2}\,du\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  $$e^{2x}+4e^x+4=(e^x+2)^2$$ and put $e^x=t$ you will finally have

$$I=\int\frac{tdt}{(t+2)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have made one mistake. Acutally $e^{2x}+4e^x+4=(e^x+2)^2$. Now we will substitute $e^x+2=u$ hence $e^xdx=du$, i.e., $e^{2x}dx=e^xdu=(u-2)du$, hence the integral becomes
\begin{align}
I=\int \frac{(u-2)}{u^2}du \\
=\log_e(u)+\frac{1}{u}+C\\
=\log_e(e^{x}+2)+\frac{2}{e^{x}+2}+C
\end{align}

Which after manipulation becomes same as given by integral calculator.

Comment: Please explain the manipulation.

Comment: The answer by integral solver is $\frac{1}{2e^x+4}\left[(e^x+2)\ln (e^{2x}+4e^x+4)+4\right]+C$ which is equal to
\begin{align}
&=\frac{(e^x+2)\ln ((e^{x}+2))^2}{2(e^x+2)}+\frac{4}{2(e^x+2)}+C\\
&=\frac{2\ln(e^x+2)}{2}+\frac{2}{e^x+2}+C\\
&=\ln(e^x+2)+\frac{2}{e^x+2}+C
\end{align} \\ which is same as the answer obtained.